# Order by ignoring the "-"

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, varchar

I've a MySQL query and want to order by a varchar field filled only with positive or negative numbers (for some reasons I cannot use an INT field). I need to ignore the minus sign ("-") before the negative numbers, i.e.:

```
132
-134
-136
137
138
-139
```

Does anyone have any idea??

Comment: A VARCHAR field will be sorted "alphabetically", not numerically.... that's why most people don't store numbers in VARCHAR fields.... why can't you use INT?

Comment: If the format is consistent (no whitespace after the `-` ever for example) and you call `ABS()` as in `ORDER BY ABS(numbercolumn)`, you should get consistent results, but really these should be stored as integers.  Are they consistently only integers in a sane format? No non-integer characters mixed in?

Comment: If you absolutely have to do things this way, cast to INT and use ABS()

Comment: Yes I know, but I've asked something different

Comment: Yes, you have asked something different, and we're asking why you couldn't do what most people do for a reason, and that is use INT in the first place.... programming isn't about finding workrounds for bad decisions, its about making the right decisions in the first place, or having a solid business reason for making otherwise bad technical decisions

Comment: I cannot use INT because in a couple of rare cases I might have the need to store a letter in association with the number (I.e. 134b or -134b)

Comment: Better to split the value and to have an INT and a separate VARCHAR suffix column, that would make your life a lot easier

Comment: I think a Databases 101 tutorial is up your alley. We don't re-use columns for gibberish. Unless you like gibberish.

Comment: @FrancescoCoschino if `INT` is not an option, why not to use `CAST()` function?

Answer (score 0):

If using `INT` is not an option for you, maybe you can use [`CAST(expr AS type)` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

I guess your expression would look like something like this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(yourField AS SIGNED)
```

Hope it helps.